# Помогите с решением задачи о разрядности чисел

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Лимит времени 2000/4000/4000/4000 мс. Лимит памяти 65000/65000/65000/65000 Кб.

Дано N натуральних чисел, що не перевищують 1015. Потрібно визначити розрядність (кількість цифр) кожного числа.

У стандартному вхідному потоці у першому рядку записано число N (0 < N < 100). В другому рядку через пропуск записано N натуральних чисел.
В стандартний вихідний потік потрібно вивести через пропуск кількість розрядів для кожного числа.

```
Приклад:
5
10 281 9898989 1 1234

Відповідь:
2 3 7 1 4
```

Comment: @Harry, надо было и условие переводить

Comment: @Grundy Вопрос все равно на грани закрытия - так зачем? :)

Comment: @Harry, уже закрыли :)

Answer (score 3):

Проблем-то...

```
int count;
cin >> count;
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s.length() << " ";
}
```

...мой вам совет - учите язык, Дейкстра не зря говорил, что не может выучить язык программирования тот, кто на своем собственном языке безграмотен...

Comment: а зачем читать число а потом его в строку загонять?..

Comment: @pavel Привычка :) Просто начал писать ввод, потом, когда написал - перечитал условие :) Исправлять было лень. Но Вы, конечно, правы. Сейчас...

Comment: Ну вроде собственный (украинский) язык человек знает :).

Comment: @andreycha Это не он знает, а copy-paste условие...

Comment: Меня смущают тестовые данные... `5 => 2, 10 => 3`...

Comment: @vp_arth первое - это число тестов

Comment: @vp_arth 5 - это количество чисел.

Comment: А, всё понял. Нормально